# Is there any way to use the same anonymous authentification for Firebase in main App and extension?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app is using Firebase authentification to store data in the firebase realtime database. This should be done by the main app and by my extension. The problem is that it seems to create two different users, one for the main app, and one for the extension. I just login like this:

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
    MyVariables.uid = user!.uid
}
```

Is there any way to share the user? I use the same plist for the main app and extension (via appgroup). It also works to write into the database - just with different user IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the token of the anonymous user with [`FIRUser.getIDTokenWithCompletion:`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRUser#-getidtokenwithcompletion). The find a secure way to pass that from the app to the extension (or vice versa) and pass it to [`FIRAuth.signInWithCustomToken:completion:`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#-signinwithcustomtokencompletion). Note that I haven't tried this myself (hence the lack of actual code), but it should work.

**Update**: Bad news. I checked with one of the our Auth engineers and it turns out that there's no API that allows passing a token to an extension that you can then use there to sign in. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. I tried it, and pass the value I get from getIDToken to signInWithCustomToken, but I get the error "Code=17000 "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."

Comment: That's a pity. It would be really cool to have a possibility to save user specific data from an extension too without forcing the user to create login credentials with mail or password - the user data is not really critical.